# DXA CTP 2.0 .NET Web app Internal Server Error

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-2.0, dxa-net, model-service

I did install successfully DXA CTP 2.0 on SDL Web 8.5 and also published all the example website pages successfully.

DXA Model service also setup successfully and up and running.

Accessing DXA Web app URL then it's getting Internal Server Error.

[image]

Content Service side - **No errors**

DXA Model service side:
On **cd_client**.2018-01-30.log

```
2018-01-30 22:46:02,051 WARN  c.t.c.XMLConfigurationReader - Warning while validating file 'cd_ambient_conf.xml' with schema 'schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd'. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ForwardedClaims'. One of '{InstanceID, ExcludedPaths, Cartridges, Cookies, ClaimStoreProvider}' is expected.
```

DXA .NET Webapp side:
cd_client.log - **No ERROR**

site.log - **ERROR**

```
2018-01-30 23:04:27,865 [10] ERROR - Item '/error-404' not found
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Item '/error-404' not found
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound() in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\PageController.cs:line 135
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\PageController.cs:line 49
```

Additional **DEBUG** Logs from Web app:

```
2018-01-30 23:10:43,607 [1] INFO  - -------- Initializing DXA Framework v2.0.0.34 --------
2018-01-30 23:10:43,612 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Logging.Log4NetLogger' for interface ILogger.
2018-01-30 23:10:43,635 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.DefaultCacheProvider' for interface ICacheProvider.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,795 [1] DEBUG - DXA Model Service found at URL 'http://localhost:8998/'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,795 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.DefaultContentProviderR2' for interface IContentProvider.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,796 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Navigation.StaticNavigationProvider' for interface INavigationProvider.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,833 [1] DEBUG - context-service-publication-evidence setting: ''
2018-01-30 23:10:44,833 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider' for interface IContextClaimsProvider.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,834 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Linking.DefaultLinkResolver' for interface ILinkResolver.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,835 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultRichTextProcessor' for interface IRichTextProcessor.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,835 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IConditionalEntityEvaluator.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,836 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.BaseMediaHelper' for interface IMediaHelper.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,841 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver' for interface ILocalizationResolver.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,841 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IUnknownLocalizationHandler.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,902 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ItemList' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,903 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 'headline'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,903 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ItemListElements' as semantic property 'itemListElement'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,904 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Article' has semantic type(s) 's:Article'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,904 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 'headline'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,904 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Image' as semantic property 'image'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,904 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Date' as semantic property 'dateCreated'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,904 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Description' as semantic property 'about'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,905 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ArticleBody' as semantic property 'articleBody'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,905 [1] DEBUG - Type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Download' has multiple SemanticEntity attributes for prefix 's'. Ignoring 'MediaObject'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,905 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Download' has semantic type(s) 's:DataDownload s:MediaObject'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,905 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Description' as semantic property 'name description'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,905 [1] DEBUG - Type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image' has multiple SemanticEntity attributes for prefix 's'. Ignoring 'MediaObject'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,906 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image' has semantic type(s) 's:ImageObject s:MediaObject'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,906 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'AlternateText' as semantic property 'name'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,906 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Place' has semantic type(s) 's:Place'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,907 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Name' as semantic property 'name'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,907 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Image' as semantic property 'image'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,907 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Address' as semantic property 'address'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,907 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Telephone' as semantic property 'telephone'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,907 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FaxNumber' as semantic property 'faxNumber'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,907 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Email' as semantic property 'email'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,907 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Location' as semantic property 'geo'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,907 [1] DEBUG - Type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.YouTubeVideo' has multiple SemanticEntity attributes for prefix 's'. Ignoring 'MediaObject'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,907 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.YouTubeVideo' has semantic type(s) 's:VideoObject s:MediaObject'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,907 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ContentList`1[[Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Teaser, Sdl.Web.Modules.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,910 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 'headline'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,910 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Link' as semantic property 'link'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,910 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ContentType' as semantic property 'contentType'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,910 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ItemListElements' as semantic property 'itemListElement'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,910 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ContentList`1[[Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Article, Sdl.Web.Modules.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,910 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 'headline'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,910 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Link' as semantic property 'link'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,911 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ContentType' as semantic property 'contentType'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,911 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ItemListElements' as semantic property 'itemListElement'
2018-01-30 23:10:44,912 [1] DEBUG - Found Device Family 'featurephone'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,912 [1] DEBUG - Found Device Family 'smartphone'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,913 [1] DEBUG - Found Device Family 'tablet'.
2018-01-30 23:10:44,913 [1] DEBUG - Found Device Family 'desktop'.
2018-01-30 23:10:45,125 [10] DEBUG - No value cached for key '/version.json' in region 'BinaryPublishDate'.
2018-01-30 23:10:45,331 [10] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/version.json' is still up to date, no action required
2018-01-30 23:10:45,500 [10] DEBUG - No value cached for key '/system/config/_all.json' in region 'BinaryPublishDate'.
2018-01-30 23:10:45,613 [10] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/system/config/_all.json' is still up to date, no action required
2018-01-30 23:10:45,624 [10] DEBUG - No value cached for key '/system/config/core.json' in region 'BinaryPublishDate'.
2018-01-30 23:10:45,655 [10] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/system/config/core.json' is still up to date, no action required
2018-01-30 23:10:45,657 [10] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://localhost:8852/' maps to Localization [5 ('English')]
2018-01-30 23:10:45,882 [10] DEBUG - No value cached for key '[36]dd2244b2-962e-4a2b-958d-8aa9ec717ff2[8]33554846[109][36]dd2244b2-962e-4a2b-958d-8aa9ec717ff2[8]33554709[4]Page[36]b0301d29-5f80-4ffd-8aba-991d61b02a07[8]33554460[4]Page[36]b0301d29-5f80-4ffd-8aba-991d61b02a07[9]100663465--Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko' in region 'RenderedOutput'.
2018-01-30 23:10:45,898 [10] DEBUG - No value cached for key 'http://localhost:8998/PageModel/tcm/5/index?includes=INCLUDE' in region 'ModelService'.
2018-01-30 23:10:45,902 [10] DEBUG - Sending DXA Model Service Request: http://localhost:8998/PageModel/tcm/5/index?includes=INCLUDE
2018-01-30 23:10:46,040 [10] INFO  - Item '/' not found
2018-01-30 23:10:46,041 [10] DEBUG - No value cached for key 'http://localhost:8998/PageModel/tcm/5/error-404?includes=INCLUDE' in region 'ModelService'.
2018-01-30 23:10:46,041 [10] DEBUG - Sending DXA Model Service Request: http://localhost:8998/PageModel/tcm/5/error-404?includes=INCLUDE
2018-01-30 23:10:46,158 [10] ERROR - Item '/error-404' not found
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaItemNotFoundException: Item '/error-404' not found
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.DefaultContentProviderR2.LoadPageModel(String& urlPath, Boolean addIncludes, Localization localization) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\DefaultContentProviderR2.cs:line 75
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.DefaultContentProviderR2.GetPageModel(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\DefaultContentProviderR2.cs:line 41
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound() in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\PageController.cs:line 123
2018-01-30 23:10:46,160 [10] ERROR - Item '/error-404' not found
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Item '/error-404' not found
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound() in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\PageController.cs:line 135
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\PageController.cs:line 49
```

**[Edit]** Further investigation, I did add the dxa-model-service paramer in the content service and restart.

Next ERROR on site:

```
2018-01-31 09:04:48,061 [22] DEBUG - Sending DXA Model Service Request: http://localhost:8998/PageModel/tcm/5/index?includes=INCLUDE
2018-01-31 09:04:48,147 [22] ERROR - DXA Model Service returned an error response: Status=500, Error='Internal Server Error', Exception='com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException', Message='com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Invalid escape sequence at line 1 column 508 path $.claimValues..DOCUMENT_ROOT', Path='/PageModel/tcm/5/index'
2018-01-31 09:04:48,149 [22] ERROR - DXA Model Service returned an error: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Invalid escape sequence at line 1 column 508 path $.claimValues..DOCUMENT_ROOT
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: DXA Model Service returned an error: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Invalid escape sequence at line 1 column 508 path $.claimValues..DOCUMENT_ROOT
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.ModelServiceClient.LoadData[T](Uri requestUri, UInt32& hash) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\ModelServiceClient.cs:line 185
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.ModelServiceClient.GetPageModelData(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\ModelServiceClient.cs:line 105
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.DefaultContentProviderR2.LoadPageModel(String& urlPath, Boolean addIncludes, Localization localization) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\DefaultContentProviderR2.cs:line 73
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.DefaultContentProviderR2.GetPageModel(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\DefaultContentProviderR2.cs:line 41
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\PageController.cs:line 28
```

[image]

[Update Edit2]
After disable the smarttarget catridge stuffs on session-content service now next appearing this error.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-01-31T10:09:18.767+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "exception": "com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.ContentProviderException",
    "message": "Item not found",
    "path": "/PageModel/tcm/5/index"
}
```

Any thought what could be missing here?

Comment: sounds like you missed one or more steps in the installation process, and now you are trying to figure out which one, would it be an option to start from scratch, since I have a feeling that will be faster than trying to fix it this way?

Comment: I did notice, I'm using the web 8.6 version since I did prepare using vagrant. Problem seems to be in ADF

Comment: Also noticed one more thing to highlight CD_8.5.0.8270, installService.ps1 $maxHttpHeaderSize="--server.max-http-header-size=65536", tomcat is missing, should be $maxHttpHeaderSize="--server.tomcat.max-http-header-size=65536", I don't know which one is correct?

Comment: 8.6 (internal SDL, cloud only) CD is the same as 8.5 - so that's not your root cause. The changes in 8.6 only affect Content Manager.

Comment: @Velmurugan did you manage to find out which one of these is correct, "server.max-http-header-size" or "server.tomcat.max-http-header-size" ?

Comment: I think it will work both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, Found the culprit by doing the detailed TRACE logs analysis and fixed.

It's because of below two items are not published from CMS.

1. **Sitemap [Navigation]** - Categories and Keywords

   [image]
2. **Generate Data Presentation** - Dynamic Component Presentation (DCP)

   [image: **enter image description here**]

   [image]

Comment: publishing the "Generate Data Presentation" component template has published some components. I wonder which components those are. Could you look it up with a where-used?

Comment: @JanH: Updated my answer

Comment: The Data Presentation Components should be published through the DXA Resolver, which will be part of the final release. As mentioned in the release notes, the CTP is not feature complete. On the Category Publishing, please leave a comment in the documentation that this is information is missing.